# Make product thumbnail into slideshow shopify collection page

Tags: javascript, html, e-commerce, slideshow, shopify

I am working on a shopify website.

On the collection / category page I am wanting to make the product image thumbnail into a slideshow so it changes the image every 4 seconds for example.

This already does this on the product page.

It already changes between two images when you hover. This simply sets display: none to one of the images then displays the other.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too large... 
This is not the same thing an automated slideshow or an event on mouse over.

All is to build on my mind.
First by choosing a jQuery plugin that suits you (Owl for example is light and nice) 
Then  by editing collection template with it  ;).